# Can't connect to my EC2 instance despite trying everything

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have created a linux EC2 and opened my SSH ports and downloaded the keypair.pem on my linux dev machine. However, despite following all the steps mentioned in the documentation, I can't connect at all using ssh. I have a public ip and dns all successfully up and running. I tried putty too (after converting to .ppk) but no luck.

The system log on the machine (through the portal) shows

```
Amazon Linux AMI release 2018.03
Kernel 4.14.181-108.257.amzn1.x86_64 on an x86_64

ip-AA-BB-CC-DDD login:
```

What could I be missing? I am a newbie, so it is probably something really stupid/silly.

Thanks

Comment: Are you getting a connection timeout with putty ?  (You do need to open port 22 on the security group in the VPC)

Comment: Are the security groups port open?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the exact command you are using and the response you are receiving. Use `ssh -vvv` to obtain debug output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things to check:

- EC2 instance is running **Linux** (done)
- EC2 instance is in a **public subnet** (defined as a subnet with a Route Table pointing to an Internet Gateway)
- EC2 instance has a **public IP address**
- EC2 instance has a **Security Group** that allows Inbound port 22 from your IP address (or wider, such as `0.0.0.0/0`)

Comment: Perfect!. the internet gateway step was what I was missing. It did not appear in any of the documentation/video that I watched in this matter.

Comment: @john-rotenstein I have this same issue. How and why do you make sure that the EC2 instance has a public IP? Can't an instance be in the public subnet, without a public Elastic IP?

Comment: @twoLeftFeet An instance can receive a public IP address either by selecting "Auto-assign Public IP" when the instance is launched, or by adding an Elastic IP address. If it is the first option, then the public IP address will change when the instance is stopped and started.